Pasar valores seleccionados de un CheckListBox a un ComboBox en C#
Estoy haciendo una aplicación de escritorio en C# para pasar los ítems de un CheckListBox a un ComboBox y estoy teniendo problema con DataRowView ya que mi variable castedItem esta en NULL y me sale un error de Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
Este es mi código para cargar mi CheckListBox:
public void CargarReportes()
    {
        ChklReportes.DataSource = BllReportes.LstReportes(18);//Consulta a la bd en Capaz
        ChklReportes.DisplayMember = "Reporte";
        ChklReportes.ValueMember = "IdReporte";
    }

Y con este código intento obtener los valores seleccionados:
foreach (object itemChecked in ChklReportes.CheckedItems)
        {
            DataRowView castedItem = itemChecked as DataRowView;
            string Reporte = castedItem["Reporte"].ToString();//Linea de error
            int Id = (int)castedItem["IdReporte"];
            CbReportes.Items.Add(Reporte);
        }

Alguien sabe que puede estar mal?
De antemano gracias!!!

el item no es un DataRowView, por lo tanto el operador as devuelve NULL, tal como está documentado.

itemChecked no es del tipo DataRowView... querias fijarte en otro lado tal vez? estas tratando de agarrar los valores chequeados?? ese for ya te los devolvio... fijate en la documentacion hay ejemplos de todo eso...

@gbianchi gracias por responder si, mi for ya me trae los valores pero lo que necesito es obtener los valores de mi campo Reporte para pasarlos a mi ComboBox

Y esos no estan en itemChecked.toString()

@gbianchi si pero viene junto a mi IdReporte y si lo paso asi con itemChecked.toString() aparece el nombre mi Clase

ItemChecked deberia ser la lista de objetos que estan chequeados. Tal vez por el tipo de lista que estas pasando es por que ves eso.. tengo que hacer memoria en forms a ver como funcionaba eso.. me fui a ver el ejemplo de la docu y decia eso... que nombre de clase te aparece??? tal vez alcanza con castear ese objeto a esa clase, y ahi si buscar las propiedades que queres...

@gbianchi el nombre me aparece asi VO.ReportesVO

entonces castea itemChecked a ese objeto, y busca los valores de ahi...
